# vim xml file type set as "ant" when name has 'build' in it

Tags: vim, file-type

When opening xml files whose name has "build" I notice that vim is setting its filetype to "ant". Can this behavior be disabled? I would like all my xml files to have filetype set as xml. Kindle help me out in this.

Comment: `:help new-filetype` may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Ant file type detective is invoked by below

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead build.xml         setf ant
```

To overwrite, just change it to xml in your ~/.vimrc

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead build.xml         setf xml
```

[vimdoc](http://vim.dindinx.net/orig/html/filetype.txt.php#%3afiletype)

Answer (score 0):

This is on line 107 of `:e $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`. It sets files with the name "build.xml" to the filetype of ant. You can copy this file to your `~/.vim` folder and edit that to comment this out.

Comment: When you copy `filetype.vim`, you have to maintain it from then on. Ted's answer shows that this isn't necessary.